# flask-sqlacodegen is not recognized as an external or internal command

Tags: python, flask

I'm try to run `flask-sqlacodegen` on my command line, but i keep getting this error:

```
flask-sqlacodegen is not recognized as an external or internal command
```

Here is what i did:

```
py -3.8 -m pip install flask-sqlacodegen
```

Which installed the library without any problem. But then, when i try to run a command from my command line, i'll get the error. Here is what i tried:

```
 py -3.8 flask-sqlacodegen  mysql://username:password@host:port/db_name --schema yourschema --tables table1,table2 --flask

py -3.8 -m flask-sqlacodegen  mysql://username:password@host:port/db_name --schema yourschema --tables table1,table2 --flask

flask-sqlacodegen  mysql://username:password@host:port/db_name --schema yourschema --tables table1,table2 --flask
```

All of them gave me the same error. I tried the same with `sqlacodegen` and still got the same error. Can anyone help me out on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that it installed it to a different directory than where your `PYTHONPATH` points to, i.e. the package itself is not present in `.../lib/python3.x/site-packages`  where your `PYTHONPATH` points to.

You can check that like so on your `cmd` line for `windows`( apply relevant cmd for your `OS`)

```
pip freeze | findstr "sqlacodegen"
```

This would return empty.

Check-in your `cmd/shell`

```
py --version
```

If this is not the same as `Python3.8` then set that to the `PYTHONPATH` of this to your environment variables. This will solve the problem.

You can also, simply install it with without `pip` by

```
git clone https://github.com/ksindi/flask-sqlacodegen.git
cd flask-sqlacodegen/
python setup.py install
```

Comment: I'm sorry! I was able to try your suggestion just now and it worked. Thank you!